# How would I take this .scrollTop code and modify it to pause it's function on Mouse Hover or Scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
window.setInterval(function() {
var elem = document.getElementById('onDiv');
elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}, 5000, 'swing');
</script>

<div id="onDiv" align="center" style="width:100%; height:250px; overflow:auto; padding-left: 2px;">
     <table id="asdf" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="min-height:250px; overflow:auto; max-height:250px; padding-left: 2px;" >
       <tr>
         <td height="250" valign="top">Content</td>
       </tr>
     </table>


 </div>
```

The code above is set to scroll down to the bottom every 5 seconds per new content added to the div.

I'm relatively new to using jQuery so there may be some incorrect formatting here. Just a heads up.

Thanks Guys/Gals!

This code that reyaner gave seems to be what I want to do, however I can't get it to work in the current declaration.

```
<script>
var IV;
function setInterval(){
IV = window.setInterval(function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('onDiv');
    elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}, 1000, 'swing');
}
setInterval();

("#onDiv").hover(function(){
clearInterval(IV);
}, function(){
setInterval();
});
</script>
```

Comment: What's that 3rd argument `"swing"` to `setInterval()`?

Comment: That's junk code that actually doesn't do anything. I never got around to adding the animate function into this jQuery code.

Comment: Both reyaner and Balint Bako's answers work actually. I really want to choose both answers. Thanks so much guys! +Rep on both of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
 var IV;
    function mysetInterval() {
        IV = setInterval(function() {
            var elem = document.getElementById('onDiv');
            elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
        }, 1000);
    }
    mysetInterval();
    $(function() {
        $("#onDiv").hover(function() {
            clearInterval(IV);
        }, function() {
            mysetInterval();
        });
    });
```

Comment: this is not stopping the scrolling, also this is your 2nd answer with the same content

Comment: it dose, but jumps always to the end when triggered... but if new content would be loaded...

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. So this is jumping and not scrolling, so you don't have to stop the animation... This has to be embedded as I wrote in a comment for my answer, which could be the problem I guess.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help diagnosing and fixing this issue!

Comment: Would you perhaps know the formatting for animating this function you created? I'm currently trying to figure it out myself but I'm having no luck. Like I said before, I appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: (copied your code in func..)

```
var IV;
function setInterval(){
    IV = window.setInterval(function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('onDiv');
        elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
    }, 5000, 'swing');
}
setInterval();

$("element").hover(function(){
    clearInterval(IV);
}, function(){
    setInterval();
});
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply. I tried this but nothing seems to happen. Is there something I need to declare in the script tag or something?

Comment: oh, are you using jquery? do you need help on the scrolling.. thout you are asking how to pause it on hover?

Comment: Haha, yeah. The code you presented is pretty close to what I want it to do actually. I just don't know how all of the jQuery variables and how it works.

Comment: <script>
var IV;
function setInterval(){
    IV = window.setInterval(function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('onDiv');
        elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
    }, 1000, 'swing');
}
setInterval();

("#onDiv").hover(function(){
    clearInterval(IV);
}, function(){
    setInterval();
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/Xn9gd/

```
var interval;

$("#onDiv").hover(function () {
    $(this).stop(true);
    clearInterval(interval);
}, function () {
    queue();
});

function queue() {
    interval = setInterval(function () {        
        $("#onDiv").animate({
            scrollTop: $("#onDiv").prop('scrollHeight')
        }, 1000);
    }, 500);
}

queue();
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks again for another reply! This method works, the only issue is that it doesn't register a hover and constantly goes down. However, this feels really close, but like you said it isn't done yet. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: That is not true :) it stops scrolling down, if you move the mouse over the div and it registers a hover, I mean take a look at the 1st handler... Or I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Ah ok. I tried it in your Fiddle space and worked fine. It just didn't seem to work on my website. http://67.215.228.244/testforum/
Everything's a WIP with me, I apologize in advance haha.

Comment: This script should be right before the `</body>` and embed it like this `<script>            
      $(document).ready(function(){
//the script form the answer
      });            
    </script> `

Comment: Same to you man, I seriously appreciate your time helping out with this small issue and taking time to help a guy out.